# How to set files in multiple file input field on page load?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm making profile update functionality, where the user has multiple images that I want to show him so that he can add new images or remove the old ones, I'm using a `js` library through which I show the preview but when I submit the form the old images are not present in that data. Can I push values into the file input fields or is there any workaround this so I can achieve this functionality.

[Link to Library that I'm using](https://github.com/promosis/file-upload-with-preview)

My Js code:

```js
var upload = new FileUploadWithPreview('myUniqueUploadId', {
    showDeleteButtonOnImages: true,
    text: {
        chooseFile: 'Įkelkite nuotrauką',
        browse: 'naršyti',
        selectedCount: 'Pasirinkti failai',
    },
    presetFiles: [
        <?php
            foreach($Workimages as $Workimg){
                echo $website_url.'master_image/'.$Workimg.','
        }?>
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to quote the image path

```
var upload = new FileUploadWithPreview('myUniqueUploadId', {
    showDeleteButtonOnImages: true,
    text: {
        chooseFile: 'Įkelkite nuotrauką',
        browse: 'naršyti',
        selectedCount: 'Pasirinkti failai',
    },
    presetFiles: [
        <?php
            foreach($Workimages as $Workimg){
                echo '"'.$website_url.'master_image/'.$Workimg.'",'
        }?>
    ],
});
```

Better way is to use json_encode array

```
<?php 
 $Workimages = array_map(function($v) use($website_url) {  return $website_url.'master_image/'.$Workimg;  }, $Workimages);
?>
var upload = new FileUploadWithPreview('myUniqueUploadId', {
    showDeleteButtonOnImages: true,
    text: {
        chooseFile: 'Įkelkite nuotrauką',
        browse: 'naršyti',
        selectedCount: 'Pasirinkti failai',
    },
    presetFiles: <?= json_encode($Workimages); >
});
```